# SQLITE Split Datetime to Logon/Logoff

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, pivot

Hy, i want to split the time to 2 columns by Event type.

My Table looks like this:

| User | EventType | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | Logon | 14.08.2022 23:51:12 |
| name2 | Logoff | 12.08.2022 09:12:44 |
| name2 | Logon | 11.08.2022 23:51:01 |
| name1 | Logoff | 16.08.2022 08:27:55 |

And i want to split the Time with EventType like this in SQLite:

| User | Logon | Logoff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 14.08.2022 23:51:12 | 16.08.2022 08:27:55 |
| name2 | 11.08.2022 23:51:01 | 12.08.2022 09:12:44 |

any ideas?

Comment: What is the quality of the data? Can you ever get missing logon or logoff events / multiple logons or logoffs in a row? If you run this after someone logs on, but before they logoff, what will the data look like and what results do you want?

Comment: i only need the data range between logon and logoff from a user. If there is only Logon and no Logoff after it, then there could be NULL or current date.

Comment: So, you don't have multiple logons and logoffs, for the same user? (log on Monday, off Tuesday, on Wednesday, off Thursday?)

Comment: ah of course, there will be logon and logoffs for the past 30 days. So there will be multiple logons for same users.

Comment: In the event of system failure you could have logon events with no corresponding logoff event. This is probably more common than you think. If it is an application it could be caused by a freeze of the O/S or Windows, someone hard powering off, power failure, closing the app. If it is a web browser than it will probably be more common than a desktop app. You will need to take these into account as well. You could also have logon events with no final logoff event if the user is actively logged on and has not yet closed the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming there is no double logons without logoff, as in your example, you can do this:

```
select user, 
       logon_time, 
       logoff_time 
  from (select user, 
               time logon_time,
               lead(time) over(partition by user order by time) logoff_time,
               event_type
          from test_table)
 where event_type = 'Logon';
```

The LEAD function takes value from next line using ordering from "order by" part. In your case a logoff event takes place only after a logon, so it might working

[db_fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kt8hAhR1XL8HK5dzd3kkJS/1)

Comment: @MatBailie you're right, fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: @MatBailie I'm ordering by time. You might be landed on the first idea. It's all should be updated now. Hmm, no idea why do you see an old version

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  session AS
(
  SELECT
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN eventtype = 'logon' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    )
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY username
          ORDER BY eventtime
    )
      AS user_session_id,
    *
  FROM
    yourData
  WHERE
    eventtype IN ('logon', 'logoff')
)
SELECT
  username,
  user_session_id,
  MIN(CASE WHEN eventtype = 'logon'  THEN eventtime END),
  MIN(CASE WHEN eventtype = 'logoff' THEN eventtime END)
FROM
  session
GROUP BY
  username,
  user_session_id
```